# How precise should be a query specified in Solr query related listeners config?

Tags: solr

If I have lots of requests which search selecting different addresses, may I use a wildcard for select query, selecting all addresses for warming in settings of query related listeners? I would like to cache all addresses to make subsequent queries of separate addresses faster. Or using wildcards for caching isn't possible?

```
<listener event="newSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
          <arr name="queries">
              <lst>
                  <str name="q">address:*</str>
                  <str name="rows">10000</str>
              </lst>
          </arr>
</listener>

<listener event="firstSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
          <arr name="queries">
              <lst>
                  <str name="q">address:*</str>
                  <str name="rows">10000</str>
              </lst>
          </arr>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query `address:*` retrieves all documents having a non-empty value in the field address, but that won't be that much useful for Solr's filter cache since a subsequent hit would only match the wildcard character as a filter.

You need to load documents where address field actually *matches a precise value*, and the wildcard character in this context will be treated as a unique filter for the filter cache, not as a cacthall.

So it's not that caching a wildcard query doesn't work but it doesn't warm the cache as you might expect/need, that is for *all distinct values* in the field (it could be useful as a "shortcut" to warm all possible results though, but imagine the cost of warming a wildcard query if the field is not restricted to a finite set..).

Instead you may have to use filter queries, each intersecting the whole set of documents (this always implies a main wildcard query `q=*:*` on which you apply a fq), and using one `fq` per possible value in the field - or per most frequently submitted values if the field is not restricted, which will load every (or the most frequently loaded) subsets of documents by addresses, which actually means warming the filter cache for each one of them.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/query-settings-in-solrconfig.html#filtercache

Comment: It will however warm the file system cache for the index files and the document cache in Solr, so it will have a purpose - warming a cache for all possible queries doesn't seem like the goal here (but if there's multiple, common queries, those should be added explicitly).

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, using 1 fq per possible/distinct value if the field is restricted to a set of possible values at index time, or per most frequently submitted values if not.